# How to mock `current_user` in flask templates?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, flask-login

I want to mock `flask-login`'s `current_user` under the template rendering. This function return the current logged user.

Right now I'm mocking the  `AnnonymousUserMixin` from `flask-login` which is returned by default if the user is not authenticated. But this leads to all kind of juggles. If I could simply mock `current_user` I would be able to create a Mocked object for it to return.

Here a sample of what I'm using today:

```
import unnittest
from flask_login.mixins import AnonymousUserMixin


class TestFoo(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch.object(AnonymousUserMixin, 'is_admin', create=True,                  
                  return_value=False)                                           
    @patch.object(AnonymousUserMixin, 'is_authenticated',  return_value=True)                                           
    def test_user_restriction(self, *args):
        ...
```

Regards,

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Okay. I found the answer.

`flask-login` will ask you to initialize a `LoginManager` instance with `login_manager.init_app(your_app)`. When you do this it add the `current_user` to your app contexts processors. This happens at `flask_login.utils._user_context_processor` function, which is defined as

```
def _user_context_processor():
    return dict(current_user=_get_user())
```

Here `_get_user` is defined at the same module. What I do to mock `current_user` is mock `_get_user` at `flask_login.utils`.

Here is a working example of how it can be done. I am printing the response content so people can see the result differing. A real test would not instantiate Test class by hand and should use `unittest.main` or something appropriated.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template_string as render_string
from flask_login import LoginManager, UserMixin

app = Flask(__name__)
loginmgr = LoginManager(app)
loginmgr.init_app(app)


class User(UserMixin):
    pass


@loginmgr.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.get(user_id)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_string('Hello, {{ current_user | safe }}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import unittest
    from unittest import mock

    class Test:
        def test(self):
            client = app.test_client()
            response = client.get('/')
            data = response.data.decode('utf-8')
            print(data)

        @mock.patch('flask_login.utils._get_user')
        def test_current_user(self, current_user):
            user = mock.MagicMock() 
            user.__repr__ = lambda self: 'Mr Mocked'
            current_user.return_value = user
            client = app.test_client()
            response = client.get('/')
            data = response.data.decode('utf-8')
            print(data)


    t = Test()
    t.test()
    t.test_current_user()
```

Here is the output of it:

```
Hello, <flask_login.mixins.AnonymousUserMixin object at 0x7f9d5ddaaf60>
Hello, Mr Mocked
```

Regards,

Comment: How can we mock current_user in order to get current_user.id = 1 and also current_user.role.name = 'Admin'?

Comment: try this `current_user.return_value.id = 1` and `current_user.return_value.role.return_value.name = 'Admin'`

Comment: I've already tried that but current_user.role.name is then actually mock object - <MagicMock name='_get_user().role.name' id='2157103942736'> instead of 'Admin'.

Comment: try `.name.return_value = 'Admin'`

Comment: Sorry, but the problem was that I used flask login_user() to login user and I just needed to use your @mock.patch('flask_login.utils._get_user') in order to get current user without defining a mock object for current_user.

Answer (score 2):

I found this [tutorial](https://realpython.com/blog/python/python-web-applications-with-flask-part-iii/)  interesting in the section **The Test**.

It says this:

> current_user needs to be accessed within the context of a request (it
>   is a thread-local object, just like flask.request). When
>   self.client.post completes the request and every thread-local object
>   is torn down. We need to preserve the request context so we can test
>   our integration with Flask-Login. Fortunately, Flask’s test_client is
>   a context manager, which means that we can use it in a with a statement
>   and it will keep the context around as long as we need it:

So in simple words, you can log in your user via post request and the `current_user` object will be available and then you can test everything you want in the code.

Here is an example:

```
with self.client:
    response = self.client.post(url_for('users.login'),
                                data={'email': 'joe@joes.com', 'password': '12345'})

    self.assert_redirects(response, url_for('index'))
    self.assertTrue(current_user.name == 'Joe')
    self.assertFalse(current_user.is_anonymous())
```

Comment: Well this is nice but my login goes to LDAP and I don't want dependent on LDAP for unit testing.

Comment: LDAP , what does it means?

Comment: LDAP is a kind of user server. Is used to keep user, credentials all sorting of stuff.