# Creating pytest suite for flask applications with flask login

Tags: unit-testing, flask, mocking, pytest, flask-login

Currently I’m developing a flask application with a few other people that requires users to be authenticated via OAuth and I’m creating an automated testing suite as we continue to develop. I’m running into issues creating authenticated mock users that have the attributes I need in order to utilize the app. Nearly every route has SQL queries related to the users data(their ID number and their profile picture) and requires login (@login_required).

I have tried a number of fixes I’ve found online but they fall short of fixing my issues. When I run the tests using [this fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47294304/how-to-mock-current-user-in-flask-templates), the magic mock object created is authenticated but doesn’t allow me to change its attributes so I get an SQL error.

I’ve tried doing a mock patch of the user loader but it didn’t yield much of anything.

That link is the closest I’ve gotten but I would love anyone’s insight on how to best create an authenticated user that has attributes I can change that is recognized for different request contexts.  I don’t want to simply disable authentication, but I want the mocked users to be authenticated and allow me to provide them with the necessary data so the SQL queries pass.

Let me know if you need any clarifications or want to see any code snippets.

Comment: I use sqllite for testing

Comment: For brevity's sake, I figured out how to make my unit tests work. By making a pytest mocker patch of the flask_login.utils._get_user that returned a User object when my client was initialized in a fixture, I was able to create the proper objects with authentication.